# How to reduce memory required to execute a code?

Tags: processing-efficiency, memory-efficient, coding-efficiency

I am a student who has had two years of experience with Java programming(only mathematical programming) and now learning C++, but never have we been taught how to efficiently manage memory for execution of a code.
I submitted my code to one of the competitions in my country, and it turned out that my java code actually used around 1000M of memory but took 0.07 seconds to execute.
How do I efficiently write a basic program with loops and variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule when optimizing is **asking yourself : do I need to optimize ?** 1000M of memory and 0.07 seconds is ok in the general case.

Second rule is **profiling**. You must run your code within a profiler to know what is taking resources (CPU or RAM).

When spotted, if you don't know how to solve the problem, **come back here with a more specific question**.

To answer your very last question. In general, you can't harm a computer with variables and loops... in general.